# CSS and Xpath : Hyphens not working

Tags: html, google-chrome, xpath

I have a line of html that looks like:

```
<td class="la de da" style="width:215px;" tabindex="-1" la-columnid="column">
```

Whenever I try to use a locator on `la-columnid` it seems to be error-ing out. I'm using the chrome console to try to do this.

Is there some way to escape the hyphen? Or another method to get it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be trying to escape the hyphen:

```
//td[@la-columnid="column"]
```

or:

```
td[la-columnid=column]
```

In the Chrome console, execute it in the following way:

```
$x('//td[@la-columnid="column"]')
```